# URL works in preview but not in actual post

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27349836/2404501) the need arose to include the URL `http://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/CHR$`. I put it directly in the text without any brackets. I knew there was a chance of that dollar sign being a problem, so I verified that it worked in the preview before posting. It worked, so I posted it like that.

Unlike the preview, the real post contained a broken link. It pointed to `.../CHR` with the dollar sign not being part of it. When I noticed this I edited the post to use `%24`

It would be nice if the preview and the actual post renderer would agree on what constitutes a URL.

Comment: Encountered that issue at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24607216/13075 as well.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR version: it's a really bad idea to use URLs that are not delimited by `<>`, but people keep messing this up**

This is what happpens when independent bits of software try to handle URLs without following the standard, [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).

In particular:

- URLs are surrounded like `<url>` in free text (page 3); `"url"` is also mentioned. If it's not surrounded, it's only a sequence of characters that sort of *looks* like a URL.
- ASCII Space, all ASCII C0 control characters, DEL, and all characters with the 8th bit set *must* be escaped (though for the last, it is defensible to allow UTF-8 these days, there might be a standard somewhere?).
- The only unsafe-in-all-urls characters are:

  <>"%{}|\^~[]`#
- The only unsafe-within-some-schemes characters are:

  ;/?:@=&
- The remaining special characters, and all ascii alphanumerics, *never* need to be escaped in a compliant system:

  $-_.+!*'(),

Ergo, this is a bug in markdown, likely caused by trying to auto-link `http://looks_like_a_url_but_really_not` instead of only linking `<http://actually_a_url_because_it's_delimited>`.  Additionally, the fundamental choice of `()` for `[link text](url)` is noncompliant, and a major cause of bugs.

Comment: I'm guessing markdown was going for human usability, rather than adherence to a spec, and hence why it recognizes URLs without surrounding delimiters. I mean, most humans don't put delimiters around URLs when they write them.

Comment: @GreenGiant I don't think the Markdown standard actually says anything about automatically detecting links. It's not really a function of the markup, anyway. It's just something StackOverflow implemented as a convenience.

Comment: `$-_.+!*'(),` are ASCII, but there are *not* alphanumeric! "Alphanumeric" means "numbers and letters".