# Inconsistent URL linking (problem with $ sign)

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

Consider the following link:

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory
```

When I enter it in the post, the preview shows me that it will be "linked" correctly:

[image: correctly rendered link]

However, after post is added, the link stops at `$` sign:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

I know I can handle this situation with markdown (and actually, I did). I just wanted to note that post preview is not consistent with added post in this situation.

Comment: I reported the same thing a few months ago: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278694/url-works-in-preview-but-not-in-actual-post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this maybe an issue with the display for `$` in the URL, IMHO, you don't want to use the naked URL in posts. Instead, you can (and most probably, you should) use it like below, atleast for sake of better readibility

*EDIT PREVIEW:*

> Consider the following [(brief link-description)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)
>
> [1]: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

*POST PREVIEW:*

Consider the following [(brief link-description)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)

Comment: Even better would be [$cacheFactory - Factory that constructs Cache objects and gives access to them.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)

Comment: @DavidPostill Right. I was trying to put it in generic words. :-)

Comment: I normally use the "page title" as the link description instead of "link" ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Agree. Update my answer, too. :-)