# Dollar ('$') character breaks link in saved answer but not in preview when creating/editing

Tags: support, bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

I just answered a question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40469713/782358) and noticed that a link I added (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog) appeared correctly in the preview but when saved the text "$mdDialog" does not appear as part of the link.

It also happens with this question.

Comment: Reported by me 23 months ago [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278694/url-works-in-preview-but-not-in-actual-post) - not expecting a fix at this point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, the markdown parser obivously gives up on seeing the $.

As a workaround, use the explicit link markup:

```
[https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog][2]
  [2]: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog
```

Which renders as:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

Or this alternative https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog to do it inline:

```
[https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)
```

A [little testing reveals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239748/158100) that also the single quote and asteriks exhibit the same flaw:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/'mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/*mdDialog

Small differences between client-side preview rendering and the final result can occur as the client-side is done by an Javascript implementation of the parser where the server side parser is implemented in C#.

Comment: Thanks. The parser works in the preview though.

Comment: @camden_kid yeah, the client side parser is javascript and the serverside is c#. Serverside your markdown is re-parsed where subtle changes can emerge.

Comment: Could you add that comment and any other info you have to your answer? Thanks again.